# Magento 2 - How to add a placeholder in company field of customer address edit form(edit.phtml)?

Tags: magento2, php

I have been trying to add a placeholder in the company field of customer address edit form(edit.phtml) in Magento 2. Any suggestion or advice where should I be looking I looked into the block of `'Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company'` but couldn't find anything helpful

> **app\design\frontend\Company_name\Magento_Customer\templates\address\edit.phtml**

getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company') ?>

```
<?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
    <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Working or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/company.phtml` file and add `placeholder` attribute in input tag.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company $block */
?>
<div class="field company <?= $block->isRequired() ? 'required' : '' ?>">
    <label for="company" class="label">
        <span>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Company')) ?>
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
            <?php
            $_validationClass = $block->escapeHtmlAttr(
                $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)
                     ->getAttributeValidationClass('company')
            );
            ?>
        <input type="text"
               name="company"
               id="company" placeholder="Company Placeholder"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getCompany()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Company')) ?>"
               class="input-text <?= $_validationClass ?: '' ?>"
         >
    </div>
</div>
```

Clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clean`

[image]

Comment: Its working well as earlier I was making changes in /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element so kinda confused

Comment: This file is proper. So do not worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this file for company field in vendor.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/company.phtml

You can override this file here in your custom theme and you can change placeholder there.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/company.phtml

Hope this will help you!